# jqplot tick angle for dateAxisRendere?

Tags: javascript, ajax

is there any way to set the angle for dateaxis render in jqplot?
i need this for x-axis.
thanks..
this is my code

```
xaxis:
                        {
                        min:'2009-11-01 00:00',
                        max:'2009-11-01 12:00',
                        renderer:jQuery.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                        tickOptions:{formatString:'%H:%M',angle:-30},
                        tickInterval:'30 minutes'
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to accomplish it:

`axesDefaults : {
            tickRenderer :$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
            tickOptions : {
                angle :30
            }
        },`